# kubectl delete pv <id> says "deleted" but hangs and the PV still exists (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I have a StatefulSet (see https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-eks-pod-no-avail-volume-zone-yml) with a `volumeClaimTemplate` and a corresponding [`StorageClass`](https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-storage-yml) definition. I run on AWS EKS.

I realized there was a problem as my pod was Pending with the warning "node(s) had no available volume zone". Looking into AWS EC2 console I noticed there was a Volume but it was not attached to the worker node, while `kubectl get pv` [listed it as OK](https://gist.github.com/holyjak/fc6e35a4228d348cf89eef5303473cab#file-describe-pv-output-sh).

I manually deleted the Volume in EC2 and try to delete the PV as well:

```
$ kubectl delete pv <id>
persistentvolume "<id>" deleted
```

but this command, despite printing "deleted" hanged and `get pv` still showed the PV.

I have tried to delete also the StatefulSet but to no avail.

Answer (score 4):

Solution: I obviously had to manually delete also the persistent volume claim (`kubectl delete pvc demo-db-storage-demo-db-deployment-0`). After that also the (obviously pending) PV delete finished. I was able to `apply` by resources again and got a new Volume, PV, PVC, and a running pod.

Comment: Oddly enough, if you delete the pvc first (`demo-db-storage-demo-db-deployment-0` in this case), it will delete the underlying pv for you.  It really should emit a message saying that it won't delete a resource that's still "in use" (claimed) and exit.